# set property value in Class By Index in List

Tags: c#

hey im trying to Set value to item in list in some class that i have

i know the property name and the type of it is bool

i tried that

and im reciving this error

System.Reflection.TargetException

what im doing wrong ?
thanks advise

```
public partial class Users
{
    public List<Member> Members { get; set; } = new List<Member>();
}

public partial class SellerSettings
{
    public bool MyProp { get; set; };
}
```

what i tried

status is always 1 or 0 that can convert to bool

```
    public async void ChangeStatus(int userId, string column, int status)
    {
        var propInfo = Users.Members[Users.Members.FindIndex(c => c.Id == userId)].SellerSettings.GetType()
            .GetProperty(column);
        if (propInfo != null)
        {
            propInfo.SetValue(column, Convert.ToBoolean(status), null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your second example, `Users.Members` appears to be an attempt to call a static property. But the property is not static. What error are you getting?

Comment: @JohnWu the error is object does not match target type

Comment: The name of the prop is 100% right , maybe my indexing to the prop is wrong ?

Comment: Where do you get the said error? Do you have a property of type `Users` named `Users`?

Comment: Users is Class that Holds The Member List
ill edit the Question and add it to just a sec

Comment: You are calling `SetValue` on `column`, meaning you are trying to set the status of a `string`. System.String doesn't have a status, of course.  I think you need your business object in there and not `column`.

Comment: @JohnWu column value is holding the property name that i want to change value

Comment: @Wellzar I understand, But the first paramter of `SetValue` is not the name of the property (the name of the property is already implicitly specified by the reference to `propInfo`). The first argument should be an instance of the class that implements `propInfo`. Not sure from your example but it should probably be an instance of `Member`.

Comment: oh so how can i get that specific instance ? 
its possible ?
its really importent to me

Comment: @Wellzar See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The first paramter of SetValue is not the name of the property (the name of the property is already implicitly specified by the reference to propInfo). The first argument should be an instance of the class that implements propInfo. Not sure from your example but it should probably be an instance of `SellerSettings`, like this:

```
public async void ChangeStatus(int userId, string column, int status)
{
    var member = Users.Members[Users.Members.FindIndex(c => c.Id == userId)];
    var settings = member.SellerSettings;
    var propInfo = settings.GetType().GetProperty(column);
    if (propInfo != null)
    {
        propInfo.SetValue(settings, Convert.ToBoolean(status), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: oh i understand now , i was needed to get member and then run it on the settings .

thank you very much sir !